# Delphi Webbroker with http.sys

Tags: delphi, webbroker

Using Delphi 11 latest version.

Is there a switch to let WebBroker use Windows built-in http.sys server instead of Indy Webserver?  If so, how to turn on the SSL certificate as well?  I imagine Microsoft's built-in http/https engine would be more robust.

For some reason, I wish to skip ISAPI so would prefer a command-line or Gui version of Webbroker running on Windows.

How robust is the built-in Indy webserver for commercial deployment - meaning up to how many simultaneous connections per second?

I'm asking because DMVC Delphi has an option to use http.sys and it is based on Webbroker, so I thought WebBroker would have supported http.sys by now.

Thanks.

Comment: "*How robust is the built-in Indy webserver for commercial deployment - meaning up to how many simultaneous connections per second?*" - the *number* of simultaneous connections is limited only by available memory. The *performance* of those connections is likely to suffer the higher you go though, since Indy uses 1 thread per client connection, which is fine when dealing with hundreds of connections, but asynchronous overlappedIO/IOCP is far more scalable and performant when dealing with thousands of connections.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I suppose if I switch to Isapi or Apache module, it will automatically use the IOCP?  is there any way to switch WebBroker to use http.sys instead of Indy webserver when running as gui/commandline?

Comment: "*is there any way to switch WebBroker to use http.sys instead of Indy*" - I have no idea. I've never worked with WebBroker. That is a question you should ask Embarcadero.

Comment: If you're considering an alternative to WebBroker, I've [used HTTPSYS API directly before...](https://github.com/stijnsanders/xxm/tree/master/Delphi/hsys)

Comment: @StijnSanders Thank you for the link.  It even has websockets support! however, I was hoping for something more straight-forward to use with Webbroker.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try [mORMot](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot).
Really high-performance framework.
You can find almost everything you need to build webservices.

Comment: Thank you. I'm aware of it but wish to stick to Delphi-standard webbroker for now.